# Create map based on viewports coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When creating a map, is it possible to, instead of specifying a center coordinate, to specify viewport coordinates?

For example, creating a map given the following viewport coordinates:

```
"viewport": {
    "northeast": {
        "lat": 43.36899968029149,
        "lng": -80.08620496970849
    },
    "southwest": {
        "lat": 43.3663017197085,
        "lng": -80.0889029302915
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm using a center location:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    zoom: 13,
    center: { lat: 48.642312, lng: -80.51857 },
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
    zoomControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map), the google.maps.Map object has a `.fitBounds` method, which takes either a [`google.maps.LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) or a [`google.maps.LatLngBoundsLiteral`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBoundsLiteral) as an argument.

```
function initialize() {
  var viewport = {
    north: 43.36899968029149,
    east: -80.08620496970849,
    south: 43.3663017197085,
    west: -80.0889029302915
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  map.fitBounds(viewport);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8gdrz3px/)

Comment: Awesome, but one more question. Is there a way to auto-zoom into the viewport so that it either the width or height of the viewport touches the edges of the map? So instead of [this](https://i.imgur.com/iSAyJFS.png), have it something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/A1YNnzI.png)?

Comment: Nope (at least not at present; can't predict the future), the API adds some padding that doesn't seem to be controllable.

Comment: Dang, that's unfortunate. Thanks though for your answer!